# How to create an arraylist loop to add information into an object

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I have this mess of code for my readData method where I had to type each object individually to add information into it. I wasn't able to figure out how to get an arrayList to to this no matter how many times I tried.

Can someone please show me how to make an arraylist where I will be able to add all this information in using a loop. Thanks

EDIT the readData method is where i'm having trouble creating a loop for the objects I'm adding information into. Is there a way that I can loop it so I don't have to have so much information and keep this part

> ```
>         person1.setStudentID(studentID);
>         inputFile.nextLine();
>         fullName = inputFile.nextLine();
>         person1.setFullName(fullName);
>         testScore = inputFile.nextDouble();
>         person1.setTestScore(testScore);
>         person1.setGrade(testScore);
>         averageScore = averageScore + testScore;
>
>         studentID = inputFile.nextInt();
>         person2.setStudentID(studentID);
>         inputFile.nextLine();
>         fullName = inputFile.nextLine();
>         person2.setFullName(fullName);
>         testScore = inputFile.nextDouble();
>         person2.setTestScore(testScore);
>         person2.setGrade(testScore);
>         averageScore = averageScore + testScore;
> ```

```
public class GradeDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String STUDENT_INFO = "HW1_Students.txt";

        List<GradeInfo> list = new ArrayList<GradeInfo>();

        Scanner inputFile = null;
        GradeInfo person1 = new GradeInfo();
        GradeInfo person2 = new GradeInfo();
        GradeInfo person3 = new GradeInfo();
        GradeInfo person4 = new GradeInfo();
        GradeInfo person5 = new GradeInfo();
        GradeInfo person6 = new GradeInfo();
        GradeInfo person7 = new GradeInfo();
        GradeInfo person8 = new GradeInfo();
        GradeInfo person9 = new GradeInfo();
        GradeInfo person10 = new GradeInfo();
        GradeInfo calculatedValues = new GradeInfo();

        list.add(person1);
        list.add(person2);
        list.add(person3);
        list.add(person4);
        list.add(person5);
        list.add(person6);
        list.add(person7);
        list.add(person8);
        list.add(person9);
        list.add(person10);

        try {
            inputFile = new Scanner(new File(STUDENT_INFO));
        }

        catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("\n *** Exception occured while opening "
                    + ex.getMessage() + " ***");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        readData(inputFile, STUDENT_INFO, person1, person2, person3, person4,
                person5, person6, person7, person8, person9, person10,
                calculatedValues);

        System.out.println(calculatedValues.getAverage());
        //Get Standard Deviation
        standardDeviation(person1, person2, person3, person4, person5, person6,
                person7, person8, person9, person10, calculatedValues);
        //Print Out the Standard Deviation value
        System.out.println(calculatedValues.getStandardDeviation());

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(list.get(i));
        }

    }

    public static void readData(Scanner inputFile, final String STUDENT_INFO,
            GradeInfo person1, GradeInfo person2, GradeInfo person3,
            GradeInfo person4, GradeInfo person5, GradeInfo person6,
            GradeInfo person7, GradeInfo person8, GradeInfo person9,
            GradeInfo person10, GradeInfo calculatedValues) {

        GradeInfo standardDeviation = new GradeInfo();
        int studentID = 0;
        String fullName = "";
        double testScore = 0, averageScore = 0, scoreHolder = 0;

        while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
            try {

                studentID = inputFile.nextInt();
                person1.setStudentID(studentID);
                inputFile.nextLine();
                fullName = inputFile.nextLine();
                person1.setFullName(fullName);
                testScore = inputFile.nextDouble();
                person1.setTestScore(testScore);
                person1.setGrade(testScore);
                averageScore = averageScore + testScore;

                studentID = inputFile.nextInt();
                person2.setStudentID(studentID);
                inputFile.nextLine();
                fullName = inputFile.nextLine();
                person2.setFullName(fullName);
                testScore = inputFile.nextDouble();
                person2.setTestScore(testScore);
                person2.setGrade(testScore);
                averageScore = averageScore + testScore;

                studentID = inputFile.nextInt();
                person3.setStudentID(studentID);
                inputFile.nextLine();
                fullName = inputFile.nextLine();
                person3.setFullName(fullName);
                testScore = inputFile.nextDouble();
                person3.setTestScore(testScore);
                person3.setGrade(testScore);
                averageScore = averageScore + testScore;

                studentID = inputFile.nextInt();
                person4.setStudentID(studentID);
                inputFile.nextLine();
                fullName = inputFile.nextLine();
                person4.setFullName(fullName);
                testScore = inputFile.nextDouble();
                person4.setTestScore(testScore);
                person4.setGrade(testScore);
                averageScore = averageScore + testScore;

                studentID = inputFile.nextInt();
                person5.setStudentID(studentID);
                inputFile.nextLine();
                fullName = inputFile.nextLine();
                person5.setFullName(fullName);
                testScore = inputFile.nextDouble();
                person5.setTestScore(testScore);
                person5.setGrade(testScore);
                averageScore = averageScore + testScore;

                studentID = inputFile.nextInt();
                person6.setStudentID(studentID);
                inputFile.nextLine();
                fullName = inputFile.nextLine();
                person6.setFullName(fullName);
                testScore = inputFile.nextDouble();
                person6.setTestScore(testScore);
                person6.setGrade(testScore);
                averageScore = averageScore + testScore;

                studentID = inputFile.nextInt();
                person7.setStudentID(studentID);
                inputFile.nextLine();
                fullName = inputFile.nextLine();
                person7.setFullName(fullName);
                testScore = inputFile.nextDouble();
                person7.setTestScore(testScore);
                person7.setGrade(testScore);
                averageScore = averageScore + testScore;

                studentID = inputFile.nextInt();
                person8.setStudentID(studentID);
                inputFile.nextLine();
                fullName = inputFile.nextLine();
                person8.setFullName(fullName);
                testScore = inputFile.nextDouble();
                person8.setTestScore(testScore);
                person8.setGrade(testScore);
                averageScore = averageScore + testScore;

                studentID = inputFile.nextInt();
                person9.setStudentID(studentID);
                inputFile.nextLine();
                fullName = inputFile.nextLine();
                person9.setFullName(fullName);
                testScore = inputFile.nextDouble();
                person9.setTestScore(testScore);
                person9.setGrade(testScore);
                averageScore = averageScore + testScore;

                studentID = inputFile.nextInt();
                person10.setStudentID(studentID);
                inputFile.nextLine();
                fullName = inputFile.nextLine();
                person10.setFullName(fullName);
                testScore = inputFile.nextDouble();
                person10.setTestScore(testScore);
                person10.setGrade(testScore);
                averageScore = averageScore + testScore;

                averageScore = averageScore / 10;

                calculatedValues.setAverage(averageScore);

            } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
                System.out
                        .println("\n *** Data doesn't match what the program expected -- "
                                + ex.toString() + " ***");
                inputFile.close();
                System.exit(-1);
            }

        } // try

    }

    public static void standardDeviation(GradeInfo person1, GradeInfo person2,
            GradeInfo person3, GradeInfo person4, GradeInfo person5,
            GradeInfo person6, GradeInfo person7, GradeInfo person8,
            GradeInfo person9, GradeInfo person10, GradeInfo calculatedValues) {
        double a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, standardDeviation;
        int x = 0;
        double sum = 0;

        a = Math.pow(person1.getTestScore() - calculatedValues.getAverage(), 2);
        b = Math.pow(person2.getTestScore() - calculatedValues.getAverage(), 2);
        c = Math.pow(person3.getTestScore() - calculatedValues.getAverage(), 2);
        d = Math.pow(person4.getTestScore() - calculatedValues.getAverage(), 2);
        e = Math.pow(person5.getTestScore() - calculatedValues.getAverage(), 2);
        f = Math.pow(person6.getTestScore() - calculatedValues.getAverage(), 2);
        g = Math.pow(person7.getTestScore() - calculatedValues.getAverage(), 2);
        h = Math.pow(person8.getTestScore() - calculatedValues.getAverage(), 2);
        i = Math.pow(person9.getTestScore() - calculatedValues.getAverage(), 2);
        j = Math.pow(person10.getTestScore() - calculatedValues.getAverage(), 2);

        double[] array = { a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j };

        while (x < array.length) {
            sum = sum + array[x];
            x++;
        }

        sum = sum / 9;

        standardDeviation = Math.sqrt(sum);
        calculatedValues.setStandardDeviation(standardDeviation);

    }

}
```

Comment: Please show your attempt to use a loop.

Comment: "Can someone please show me how to make an arraylist where I will be able to add all this information in using a loop" what part of your entire class do you consider "all this information"?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the readData method part where I'm adding the information to the objects like person1. I'll edit the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the loops that I think you are looking for. The top loop will enable you to initialize the GradeInfo objects and add them directly to the arraylist. The second loop will place all of the information into the objects stored in the arraylists. You may have to tweak them to your specific needs, but this should give you a good start.

```
ArrayList<GradeInfo> list = new ArrayList<GradeInfo>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        GradeInfo gInfo = new GradeInfo();
        list.add(gInfo);
    }

    int testScore;
    ArrayList<GradeInfo> list = new ArrayList<GradeInfo>();
    for(int x = 0; x < list.size(); x++)
    {

        list.get(x).setStudentID(inputFile.nextInt());
        inputFile.nextLine();
        list.get(x).setFullName(inputFile.nextLine();
        testScore = inputFile.nextDouble();
        list.get(x).setTestScore(testScore);
        list.get(x).setGrade(testScore);
        averageScore = averageScore + testScore;


    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked very well. I was confused when I looked at it yesterday but tried it again and it works terrifically.